# Как избежать многократного повторения пустого кода?

Tags: java, алгоритм

Есть условно большой массив (несколько десятков тысяч элементов) и 3 коротких(0-5 элементов). Заранее количество элементов в коротких массивах неизвестно. Необходимо пошагово пройти по большому массиву и, если определенный короткий не пуст, запускать соответствующий ему метод, а если пуст метод не запускается. Схематически код на Java получился такой:

```
for (String sw: bigMass) {
     if(!shortMass.isEmpty())
          MethodOne();
     if(!shortMass2.isEmpty())
          MethodTwo();
     if(!shortMass3.isEmpty())
          MethodThree();
}
```

Все работает, но вот если какие-то из коротких массивов пустые - как избавится от проверки на каждом шаге? Нельзя ли после получения данных о коротких массивах спроектировать цикл так, чтобы не было ненужных опросов? Можно решить задачу с помощью фильтров, но тогда большой массив будет сканироваться неоднократно, пусть от фильтра к фильтру он и будет уменьшаться.

Comment: почему не вывести `!shortMass.isEmpty()` для каждого массива перед запуском цикла в переменные boolean? тогда вы проерите массив на пустоту только 1 раз, а остальное время будет основываться на этих результатах

Comment: ну вообще говоря я так и делаю, решение в запросе было для краткости , но все равно булевы переменные придется проверять на каждом шаге.

Comment: ну уже проще вряд ли возможно. если вы загляните в код метода isEmpty(), то увидите что она сравнивает размер массива с нулем. размер, который же хранится в объекте. т.е. он даже не пересчитывает размер массива, а берет из переменной. сам метод isEmpty() под капотом уже достаточно оптимизирован. вы же еще упростили его. даже не представляю, куда больше))

Comment: Почему вас беспокоит проверка на каждой итерации? Профилировщик показал что она тормозит?

Comment: нет все норм, просто как-то некрасиво )

Comment: Внутри MethodXXX если первым делом проверять на пустоту и выходить?

Answer (score 2):

Создаёте "список" методов с учётом их сигнатур, который заполняется в зависимости от пустоты соответствующих массивов и вызываете каждый метод во вложенном цикле / при помощи `forEach`:

```java
private List<Runnable> fillMethodList() {
    List<Runnable> methods = new ArrayList<>();

    if (!shortMass1.isEmpty()) methods.add(this::Method1);
    if (!shortMass2.isEmpty()) methods.add(this::Method2);
    if (!shortMass3.isEmpty()) methods.add(this::Method3);

    return methods;
}

List<Runnable> methods = fillMethodList();

for (String sw: bigMass) {
    methods.forEach(Runnable::run);
}
```

---

Если понадобится передавать параметр `sw` внутрь методов `Method1(String s)`, следует использовать `Consumer<String>` вместо `Runnable`.

```java
private List<Consumer<String>> fillConsumerList() {
    List<Consumer<String>> methods = new ArrayList<>();

    if (!shortMass1.isEmpty()) methods.add(this::consume1);
    if (!shortMass2.isEmpty()) methods.add(this::consume2);
    if (!shortMass3.isEmpty()) methods.add(this::consume3);

    return methods;
}

    List<Consumer<String>> methods = fillConsumerList();
    String[] bigMass = {"a", "b"};

    for (String sw: bigMass) {
        methods.forEach(action -> action.accept(sw));
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо, это то, что я хотел!

Comment: Тогда можете поставить зеленую галочку и/или проголосовать за ответ

Answer (score 0):

1. Можно вынести вычисление isEmpty за цикл, даст совершенно незначительную экономию, так как этот метод не тяжелый:

```js
var sm1 = !shortMass.isEmpty();
var sm2 = !shortMass2.isEmpty();
var sm3 = !shortMass3.isEmpty();
for (String sw: bigMass) {
     if(sm1)
          MethodOne();
     if(sm2)
          MethodTwo();
     if(sm3)
          MethodThree();
}
```

2. Можно сделать отдельные циклы для каждой из ситуаций получиться 6 блоков:

```js
var sm1 = !shortMass.isEmpty();
var sm2 = !shortMass2.isEmpty();
var sm3 = !shortMass3.isEmpty();

if(sm1 && !sm2 && !sm3){
    for (String sw: bigMass) {
         MethodOne();
    }
}
if(!sm1 && sm2 && !sm3){
    for (String sw: bigMass) {
         MethodTwo();
    }
}
if(!sm1 && !sm2 && sm3){
    for (String sw: bigMass) {
         MethodThree();
    }
}
if(sm1 && sm2 && !sm3){
    for (String sw: bigMass) {
         MethodOne();
         MethodTwo();
    }
}
if(!sm1 && sm2 && !sm3){
    for (String sw: bigMass) {
         MethodTwo();
         MethodThree();
    }
}
if(sm1 && !sm2 && sm3){
    for (String sw: bigMass) {
         MethodOne();
         MethodThree();
    }
}
if(sm1 && sm2 && sm3){
    for (String sw: bigMass) {
         MethodOne();
         MethodTwo();
         MethodThree();
    }
}
```

Оптимальнее не куда, но читаемость приноситься в жертву.

Похоже вы пытаетесь оптимизировать, то что не требует оптимизации.